# Facebook JS SDK CORS problems

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cors, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working with Facebook js SDK "Go Live Dialog" for live streaming, every thing works fine until the last step when I want to publish the stream and I can't publish because there is a CORS error, it is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph2.facebook.com/v2.5/10154376393778843?access_token=EAAOAPyi8mX....&suppress_http_code=1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, https://www.facebook.com/', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://www.facebook.com/' is therefore not allowed access.

the issue is due to graph2.facebook.com is sending CORS header twice:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://facebook.com/

and Google Chrome accepts only one.

I opened it as a [bug on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/260047391080232) but until now their answers is to "disable CORS security" on my browsers, **a bad solution if I want to make my app public for every one.**

The code for the app is this:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '452751035113070',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>
 <button id="liveButton">Create Live Stream To Facebook</button>
 <script> 
 document.getElementById('liveButton').onclick = function() {
 FB.ui({
 display: 'popup',
 method: 'live_broadcast',
 phase: 'create',
 }, function(response) {
 if (!response.id) {
  alert('dialog canceled');
  return;
 }
 console.log('stream url:' + response.secure_stream_url);
 FB.ui({
  display: 'popup',
  method: 'live_broadcast',
  phase: 'publish',
  broadcast_data: response,
 }, function(response) {
 console.log("video status: \n" + response.status);
 });
 });
 };
 </script>
```

also here here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Aq0hkCTh5suXfOl6qKuN?p=preview .
To make a real try you should start an streaming using wowza or similar, if not, the publish button is disabled and the problem occurs when I click the publish button.

did someone know how to handle it to allow all users to use the script and to force them to use other browsers or to disable the security options? or I need to wait until facebook fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I Disable a Chrome extension and it works.

The extension is:  JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.9

this is strange because every post talk about you can't have 2 CORS directives and I think the server keeps sending 2 directives or maybe the server send just 1 and this extensions modify the headers...I don't know, but now ir works.